Why does my PWA keep crashing on my Android phone?
I am developing an PWA, but all of a sudden my installed PWA has started crashing. I see the following error message when I click on the icon. I have tried uninstalling it and re installing it, clearing the browser charge cache, but nothing has helped.
The app works perfectly locally on my laptop. And it also works well then accessed as a normal website but crashes on my Android phone when I try and it via the PWA icon. It also works perfectly in other people's Android phone.

Tbh I don't think I need to say this to someone who seems already accustomed to making stack overflow questions, but you might want to add some code you think could be problematic or more information about your phone, maybe try to get an error message. Check out how to ask because I hope you do understand we don't know anything about your issue apart from "my pwa crashes on my phone" and "it works everywhere else".  I'd say a good start is to get the error message to even know whats not working.

@GreenSaiko I don't get any error messages on my phone apart from the image I have attached. My PWA app runs without any error messages on my local machine.
Perhaps you might know how/where to extract error messages on the phone? If so kindly advise

It would be one thing to extract the error message if it also crashed on an emulated phone or on the local machine. For PWAs you should be able to use the devTools of the browser. For a Chromium based browser, you can try remote debugging. Other options would be to use android emulators. But obviously, for whatever you use, you need to log the error messages to the console.

Yesterday it happend in my Android PDA. After re-installing the pwa. Did you find somenthing about?
